# How do I set a users UserPrincipleName in LDAP through ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

Here is what I've tried:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, "dev", "cn=" + SupplierName + ",cn=suppliers,o=dd");

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, Username);

user.UserPrincipalName = Username;
```

No errors occur, but the changes are not made in LDAP.

Comment: You code retrieves the user from LDAP and change the user name but never saves the user back.

Comment: `user.Save()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Save()` method.

```
User.Save()
```

Comment: Is it updating the UserPrincipalName now?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes.